# Как получить доступ к методам класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

Я получаю объект `obj1` из словаря `db1`

Я точно знаю что это объект класса `x`, 
но я не могу получить доступ к методам данного класса.
Как преобразовать `obj1` к классу `x`, чтобы получить доступ к его методам.

```
obj1.metod1()
```

фрагмент кода класса

```
class prodObject(object):
def __init__(self, prodName, element=None):
    self.prodname = prodName
    self.elements = []
    if element is not None:
        self.elements.append(element)

    def getelEmentInProducts(self):
        result = self.elements
        return result
```

фрагмент кода где вылетает ошибка

```
def getelEment(name):
result = []
for inst in database2:
    promData = database2[inst]
    if promData.getelEmentInProducts().__contains__ (name):
        if not result.__contains__(promData):
            result.append (promData)
return result
```

фрагмент кода который в котором идёт вызов данного метода

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
gdb = database.getelEment ('a3')
```

код ошибки

**if promData.getelEmentInProducts().__contains__ (name):

AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'getelEmentInProducts'**

Вся проблема в этой строке

```
if promData.getelEmentInProducts().__contains__ (name):
```

а точнее в том что **promData** почему то имеет класс **object** а должен быть **prodObject**

Comment: Вот так obj1.metod1() и получить. Если у вас это не работает — покажите весь код, который не работает ([mcve]), и не забудьте приложить текст ошибки

Comment: отредактировал, надеюсь будет понятно.

Comment: Не совсем, непонятно что и как хранится в `database2` (а ещё в коде отступы неправильные, неаккуратно код отформатировали)

Comment: Если попытаться додумать ваш код и собрать с него запускабельный пример, то он работает и ошибок не пишет https://pastebin.com/NBPf29H4 — так что вы явно забыли добавить в вопрос что-то ещё важное

Comment: database2 обычный словарь (dict) в котором строковый ключ и значение в виде экземпляра класса **prodObject**

Comment: Посмотрите код по ссылке выше, я сделал именно такой словарь (ключ числовой, но это не важно) и всё отлично работает, ошибок у меня нет. Так что вы всё равно что-то не договариваете

Comment: да, посмотрел, пойду капаться дальше, появилась одна мысль, возможно причина где то в импорте, или по тому что код находится в разных модулях.

Comment: Примечание первое: изучите `print(database2)` — возможно, туда каким-то образом попал не prodObject, а что-то левое

Comment: Примечание второе: проверить наличие или отсутствие элемента в массиве можно кодом вида `if promData not in result` — нет никакой необходимости вызывать `__contains__` напрямую, это некрасиво

Comment: а что за объект в исключении `AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'getelEmentInProducts'` имеется ввиду это `'object'`? Как вы создаёте словарь `database2`?